# dropping all the column from dataframe while joining 2 dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm joining two Dataframes and adding some columns using `withColumn` method in my final dataframe I want all the columns from first dataframe and new columns which i have added using `withcolumn` method i want to drop all the columns from second dataframe is there any method to drop all the column from 2nd dataframe currently I'm using separate drop method foe every column.

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"))
        .drop(df2("name"))
        .drop(df2("lastname"))
```

is there any way to drop all the column using single method instead of dropping separately.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as below and please find the inline comments for the code exaplanation

```
val df2ColumnList = df2.columns    // Get the list of df2 columns
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"))
             .drop(df2ColumnList : _*)  // You can pass the list to drop function
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `drop` will only take one value of type `Column` & multiple value of type `String`.

If you pass multiple values of type `String` there could be chances of having same column in both joining DFs, you might be loosing that column related data.

Instead dropping columns select only required columns like below.

```
val columns = df1.columns.map(c => df1(c)).toList ::: List(col("with_column_a"),col("with_column_b"))

val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id")).select(columns:_*)
```

**Or**

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"))
df2.columns.map(column => df2(column)).foldLeft(df3)((ddf,column) => ddf.drop(column))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach when you have multiple columns to `drop` from a join is by using `.select`

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"))
.select("Select all the columns you need")
```

This way you don't need to think much about if you have dropped the column you need as there might be ambiguous columns in both the dataframes.

Also you can use `.selectExpr()` to do aliasing using `as` while selecting the column